# What does JBoss EAP 7 require JDK or JRE 8?

Tags: jboss-eap-7

For environments other than DEV, can I use JRE instead of JDK for JBoss EAP 7 as recommanded by Red-Hat ?

Answer (score 1):

JDK and JRE both will work. With JRE some monitoring tool like jconsole,jstack,jmap,jvisualvm..etc are not available. So normally Red Hat recommend to use JDK. If you dont want to use these monitoring tool then you can go with JRE.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to JDK while developing or testing the project, as it will give you more options.

But JRE would work fine if don't want to use other supports like monitoring tools, maven etc is not needed.

Comment: There is a also Redhat solution explaining this more detail: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18259